# Probability of not detecting fire if two of the sensors don't work well

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following problem of probability:

"In a certain factory, there is an alarm system composed of 5 sensors that work independently to detect fire. The probability that a sensor works well, that is, warns people when there's fire is $0.8$. If two of the sensors don't work well, which is the probabilty of not detecting the fire?".

I have thought of Bayes $p(A|B)$ where A="Not detecting fire" and B="2 sensors don't work well". In this way, I have computed the probability as:

$$\frac{1*0.2^5}{\binom{5}{2}0.2^2*0.8^3}$$.
However, the result of this isn't the one that appears in the solutions of the textbook because the solution should be $0.008$. Any help to approach the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Because it is not completely evident what event "detecting the fire" might be relative to the sensors (would it be a condition to which at most of the sensors could respond or not?) and because "don't work well" is a vague condition (maybe it means their detection probability falls below 0.8, but to what value exactly?), the first step is to clarify both of these.  Then you should consider whether Bayes' theorem is needed at all.